# In which of his works did Mussorgsky include features of human speech?

Tags: classical-music

The [wiki page on Speech-to-song illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech-to-song_illusion) says:

> Many composers, including Gesualdo, Monteverdi, and Mussorgsky, have
> argued that expressivity in music can be derived from inflections in
> speech, and they have included features of speech in their music.

I wonder in which ones of his works exactly Mussorgsky included features of human speech?

Comment: The wikipedia article cites the book *Musical Illusions and Phantom Words: How Music and Speech Unlock Mysteries of the Brain* by Diana Deutch. It [appers to discuss](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Musical_Illusions_and_Phantom_Words/EAuXDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=mussorgsky) *Pictures at an Exhibition* and the song cycle "The Nursery." Have you tried finding this book? Also, I don't have JSTOR access at the moment, but [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/901395) might discuss Mussorgsky; it certainly seems important to the history of the topic.

Comment: I'd be curious what this author means when they say "features of speech." It seems to me so broad as to allow for a very obvious answer: Mussorgsky's operas, or any other work that includes voice. Another go-to may be the first of the "Songs and Dances of Death," which includes a dialogue between a grieving mother and Death.

Comment: @Richard See the linked article; the context is about mapping musical pitches to imitate the inflection of spoken language, a la Steve Reich's *Different Trains*.